# Passing parameter to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I am trying to pass a custom attribute to a script. If I pass it this way:

```
$('a.load-local-image').cluetip( {
local:true, 
leftOffset: $("#par-1").attr("leftpos")
);
```

it works fine. However, I need to pass attribute of the *current* element, not just par-1. If I try it this way:

```
$('a.load-local-image').cluetip( {
local:true, 
leftOffset: $(this).attr("leftpos")
);
```

the function sees the parameter as not being passed at all. If I try it this way:

```
$('a.load-local-image').cluetip( {
local:true, 
leftOffset: function() {return $(this).attr("leftpos");}
);
```

it passes the literal string "function() {return $(this).attr("leftpos");}" as the parameter.

I know "$(this).attr("leftpos)" returns the correct value, because when I add this hack immediately above the function call:

```
$("a.load-local-image").mouseover(function(){
    alert("leftpos=" + $(this).attr("leftpos"));
});
```

it displays "leftpos=220".

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="par-1">
    <a id="load-local" class="load-local-image featurelink" title="" href="" rel="#whatever" leftpos="220" toppos="48">
    <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="" class="featureimg"></a>
```

I'm just trying to pass the value of leftpos of the current element to the function. Can someone please help me sort this out. Thanks!

Comment: There is no `leftpos` attribute on the `img`. It's on the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no leftpos attribute on the `img`, the leftpos attribute is on the `a`. This could be part of your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if the example is incorrect, but Tom is right, trying to get the `leftpos` attribute from the img tag will return undefined since the attribute is missing from the img tag. Since it is on the anchor tag, replace `$(this).find("img").attr("leftpos")` with `$(this).attr("leftpos")`

Comment: Okay, one more time: it's returning the right value. I am displaying it. I have tried putting the leftpos attribute on every element in the div (including the div) with the same results. However, I am taking it out in the example as everyone seems fixated on that. That is not the issue. The issue is that the function parameter won't pass the value being returned by $(this).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `this` object does not get modified in a parameter. The `this` object will remain the `this` object from the calling context.

```
$('#foo').click(function () {

    // right here the "this" object refers to $('#foo')

    $('a.load-local-image').cluetip({
        local: true, 
        leftOffset: $(this).find("img").attr("leftpos")
        //            ^- refers to $('#foo') also (same context)
    });
});
```

when you did this:

```
$("a.load-local-image").mouseover(function(){
    alert("leftpos=" + $(this).find("img").attr("leftpos"));
    //                   ^- refers to the $('a.load-local-image') that the event was run on
});
```

The `this` object did indeed contain the object that you wanted but that is because when you have a function run on an event the `this` object contains the element that the event was triggered on.

EDIT:

To achieve what you were trying to achieve with the `this` object you could just do this:

```
$('a.load-local-image').cluetip({
    local: true, 
    leftOffset: $('a.load-local-image').attr("leftpos")
});

Or:

$("a.load-local-image").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).cluetip({
        local: true, 
        leftOffset: $(this).attr("leftpos")
    });
});
```

EDIT #2:

The reason the cluetip would not open the first time was because you need to do this.

```
// create the cluetip instance:

$("a.load-local-image").cluetip();

// now that the cluetip is created you can call it like this:

$("a.load-local-image").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).cluetip({
        local: true, 
        leftOffset: $(this).attr("leftpos")
    });
});
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I suspected it was a timing thing. I tried nesting the function call inside a mouseover function but it still does the same thing. How do I pass the value of that attribute to the function?

Comment: To get the attribute from the element you run the function on you would have to just reuse the selector instead of using the `this` object. See edit.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! The second example works (the first one always returns the first occurance) except for one wierd thing: cluetip does not execute on the first mouseover. I have to roll the mouse across the image twice to get it to execute. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: I tried hover, mouseenter and mouseleave as well with the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Try this JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NerfAnarchist/8MJQX/). This works fine for me. Maybe your moving the mouse to fast and the mouse skips over the element? or maybe you're using an old version of jQuery? Also I have never used cluetip before so I don't know if this is a problem with the plugin or not.

Comment: I had an idea maybe the cluetip plugin needs to be run once first to initialize the plugin?

Comment: Mouseover function is running when I mouse over it (fast or slow). It's just not firing the cluetip routine. I never had that problem until I wrapped it in mouseover. Jquery = 1.10.1. Have you tried 2.0? I'll keep fiddling. Any more ideas, please let me know. Thanks, Michael!

Comment: Michael, is there any way to make your first solution "leftOffset: $('a.load-local-image').attr("leftpos")" element specific? It would work but it always references the first element with a leftpos attribute.

Comment: You could give each `$('a.load-local-image')` an ID and use those like this: `leftOffset: $('#yourID').attr("leftpos")`

Comment: I had thought that as well, Michael, and tried it before. It still required 2 mouse passes to activate the tip. There is some wierd deal with using $(this) that requires 2 passes to activate the tip. This function is used hundreds of times in the site (it shows additional information when you hover over anything) and does a really nice job of it, except when you try to pass $(this). I know this sounds like a hack, but is there any way to pass a variable that contains the prestored value of leftpos?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry but the only advice I can give you is to check their demos and find out how they did their mouseover.

Comment: There are no examples of passing variables in the demo. Everything they do is using literals - which works fine. Also hard-coding the element name works fine. Everything works fine except when I try to pass it something from $(this). I have looked at their code. It is very messy, but to try to implement another tip script at this stage would be difficult. I really appreciate your help on this, Michael. If you think of anything else, please let me know.